# Why is folder creation macro causing Error Code 76?

Tags: excel, vba, mkdir

I am using some very basic coding to create folders and subfolders automatically.  I understand the code isn't elegant however others should be able to maintain it.

The goal is to create a named folder on the desktop with name subfolders.  The code works fine on my computer but is throwing an error 6 on other computers.  Can you assist?

[Business_Name] is a named field in the spreadsheet

```
MkDir Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & [Business_Name]
MkDir Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & [Business_Name] & "\1. Sales"
MkDir Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & [Business_Name] & "\1. Sales\1. Accepted Quote and Contract"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message? Note that you will get an error if the folder already exists (so you need to check that). And please provide the exact value of `[Business_Name]` in case of the error. If you use non-allowed characters it will also throw an error.

Comment: I have checked first line and working fine for me. Check user permission/duplicate folder name/illegal character etc.

Comment: Sometimes, when (on the other computers) is OneDrive installed, the `Desktop` folder path includes `OneDrive` after User profile folder. It will be good to check that... And the error message will be elocvent in such a case. What does it show?

Comment: Could the error number be 76, instead of 6...?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The [Business_Name] is a simple string.  I could dim as string for that variable

Comment: @FaneDuru - the error code being thrown is Run-Time Error 76, path not found.  I debug.printed the path on another computer and it didnt show the OneDrive path

Comment: Try putting before the line trowing the error: `Debug.Print Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & [Business_Name]: Stop`. What does it return in Immediate Window when the code stops? Can you post here the exact `[Business_Name]` throwing the error?

Comment: @FaneDuru  Do you think that "C:\Users\Public\'  file dir will be more common than    'Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\'   I'll have to get onto one of my colleague's computers as it works flawlessly on mine.

Comment: @Pilchy: I do not think so... Only if your `Environ("Userprofile")` does not return correctly... Even in such a situation, you can redefine System Environment variables.

Comment: @Pilchy:  But you did not say anything about what `Debug.Print` returned... Is it the correct path? According to the error number it is not. Maybe, besides OneDrive, some other cloud applications do such modifications. Just maybe, but you will see that only looking in Immediate Window and using my above suggestion. To see Immediate Window you must press Ctrl + G being inside VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor)...

Comment: @FaneDuru  I finally figured it out.  Some people have OneDrive installed on their computer which meant there wasnt a Desktop for where I expected one to be.  This was causing the error.

Comment: @Pilchy: So, I was right. I will post an answer... If you will vote it up and tick the left code side check box, to make it **accepted answer** it will be OK. If not, it will be OK, too. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code problem may be strictly connected to the path as it is built...

Sometimes, when (on the other computers) is OneDrive installed, the Desktop folder path includes OneDrive after User profile folder. It will be good to check this aspect... The error message will be elocvent for such a case (Run-Time Error 76, instead of 6).

Try, please

```
Debug.Print Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & [Business_Name]: Stop
```

and see what it returns in Immediate Window...